# Correct JSON object can't be read

Tags: java, maven, gson

I have an object that I want to parse to a JSON string. When I want to read it out, it says it can't parse it back to an object (i think). This is the error:[image]

As you can see at the top of the console, the JSON object is set properly with the right brackets. What I understand from the JSONSyntaxException is that it doesn't recognize it as a JSON object. I've copied this code from my school and in a different project it does work. I don't know why it doesn't work in my Maven project.

**EDIT**
This is the code for RESTcontroller.java.

```
public PlayerDTO addPlayer(String name, String password) {
    PlayerDTO playerRequest = new PlayerDTO(NOTDEFINED, name, password);
    String queryPost = "/player";
    PlayerResponse response = executeQueryPost(playerRequest, queryPost);
    return response.getPlayers().get(0);
}

private PlayerResponse executeQueryPost(PlayerDTO playerRequest, String queryPost) {
    final String query = url + queryPost;
    log.info("[Query POST] : " + query);

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(query);
    httpPost.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    StringEntity params;
    try{
        params = new StringEntity(gson.toJson(playerRequest));
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(playerRequest));
        httpPost.setEntity(params);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(SeaBattleGame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
    return executeHttpUriRequest(httpPost);
}

private PlayerResponse executeHttpUriRequest(HttpUriRequest httpUriRequest) {

    // Execute the HttpUriRequest
    try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
         CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpUriRequest)) {
        log.info("[Status Line] : " + response.getStatusLine());
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        final String entityString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        log.info("[Entity] : " + entityString);
        return gson.fromJson(entityString, PlayerResponse.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.info("IOException : " + e.toString());
        PlayerResponse playerResponse = new PlayerResponse();
        playerResponse.setSuccess(false);
        return playerResponse;
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        log.info("JsonSyntaxException : " + e.toString());
        PlayerResponse playerResponse = new PlayerResponse();
        playerResponse.setSuccess(false);
        return playerResponse;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the code gave me this code and it does work in their project!

Comment: You're having a NullPointerException. Can you provide the code in RestController.java? apparently the issue is in the addPlayer method

Comment: So which line is line 46?

Comment: `return response.getPlayers().get(0);` is line 46

Comment: Even with a cUrl command it still doesn't work, it gives the same error

Comment: @Normalerd try this -> params =  new StringEntity( gson.toJson(playerRequest), ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);

Answer (score 0):

It would seem to me that your request is failing with this error: `Problem accessing /seabattle/player Reason: request failed`. It's not very discriptive, but it's something.

Your code is then failing with a `NullPointerException`, I'm guessing `response.getPlayers()` is returning a `null`.

You should really try and send a similar JSON to this endpoint from a curl command or via Postman app and see if it works. Or if you can, see the webserver logs to find out what the actual problem is.

EDIT: You should really also check the response status before trying to parse it. This will get rid of the `NullPointerException` and will make your code better in general.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to fix the issue:

1. In the method `executeQueryPost` you have to add the following headers for the request:

```
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

And the code should look like the following:

```java
private PlayerResponse executeQueryPost(PlayerDTO playerRequest, String queryPost) {
    final String query = url + queryPost;
    log.info("[Query POST] : " + query);

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(query);
    httpPost.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    StringEntity params;
    try{
        params = new StringEntity(gson.toJson(playerRequest));
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(playerRequest));
        httpPost.setEntity(params);

        // Need to add the following headers
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(SeaBattleGame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
    return executeHttpUriRequest(httpPost);
}
```

In case the the code continue failing is because it can't create the new player. You must handle the exception in `addPlayer()` method. Before the return check if the object returned by  `executeQueryPost` is not null.

**Update**:

The code may be failing just because the service in: http://localhost:8090 isn't running that's why it getting `500` as response.

Comment: This does help a lot. If I read the httpPost object through the console, it shows this: ` POST http://localhost:8090/seabattle/player HTTP/1.1`. I don't know if I need to see the JSON object aswell?

Comment: @Normalerd can you verify if the service in localhost:8090 is running ?

Comment: I can assure you that the service in localhost:8090 is running

Comment: @Normalerd Well, is kind of hard to tell. I can think in too many possible reason of why is failing but will be better checking the project, and if it's possible upload the project to github. Of course only if this is a personal project.

Comment: Of course, it is running. It is returning HTML responses.